# Losing timezone-awareness from pandas DateTimeIndex in Python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm on pandas 0.13.1. Assume I need to index data by two timestamps in a hierarchical index using timezones, this approach works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
dti1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=pd.Timestamp('20000101'), end=pd.Timestamp('20000102'), freq='D', tz='EST5EDT')
dti2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=pd.Timestamp('20000102'), end=pd.Timestamp('20000103'), freq='D', tz='EST5EDT')
pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([list(dti1), list(dti2)])
```

I get:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[2000-01-01 00:00:00-05:00, 2000-01-02 00:00:00-05:00], [2000-01-02 00:00:00-05:00, 2000-01-03 00:00:00-05:00]], 
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 1]])
```

while

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([dti1, dti2])
```

returns a timezone naive index:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[2000-01-01 05:00:00, 2000-01-02 05:00:00], [2000-01-02 05:00:00, 2000-01-03 05:00:00]],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 1]])
```

Would expect the two returning the same, both timezone-aware. Is this expected?

Comment: this is fixed in 0.14.0

Comment: fixed here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7090

Comment: Thanks Jeff! Should have seen that... This relates to my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805307/losing-timezone-awareness-when-saving-hyerarchical-pandas-datetimeindex-to-hdf5

Comment: yep, answered that one; its not implemented for fixed format, use table format.