# Losing timezone-awareness when saving hyerarchical pandas DatetimeIndex to hdf5 in Python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, hdf5, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm on pandas 0.14.1. Assume I need to index data by two timestamps in a hierarchical index using timezones. When saving the resulted DataFrame to hdf5 I seem to lose timezone-awareness:

```
import pandas as pd
dti1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=pd.Timestamp('20000101'), end=pd.Timestamp('20000102'), freq='D', tz='EST5EDT')
dti2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=pd.Timestamp('20000102'), end=pd.Timestamp('20000103'), freq='D', tz='EST5EDT')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([dti1, dti2])
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=mux, columns=['a'])
```

Here `df` has timezones:

```
                                                     a
2000-01-01 00:00:00-05:00 2000-01-02 00:00:00-05:00  0
2000-01-02 00:00:00-05:00 2000-01-03 00:00:00-05:00  0
```

After saving and loading to hdf5, timezone information seems to disappear:

```
df.to_hdf('/tmp/my.h5', 'data')
pd.read_hdf('/tmp/my.h5', 'data')
```

results in:

```
                                         a
2000-01-01 05:00:00 2000-01-02 05:00:00  0
2000-01-02 05:00:00 2000-01-03 05:00:00  0
```

I wonder if there is a good workaround and whether this is a know bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported under `fixed` format when using a multi-index. I guess should probably raise not implemented I supposed. Here's an issue to track [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7775)

See full-hdf5-interface docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables)

```
In [11]: pd.read_hdf('/tmp/my.h5', 'data').index.levels[0]
Out[11]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2000-01-01 05:00:00, 2000-01-02 05:00:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

But if you specify `table` format it works.

```
In [13]: df.to_hdf('/tmp/my.h5', 'data2', format='table')

In [14]: pd.read_hdf('/tmp/my.h5', 'data2')
Out[14]: 
                                                     a
2000-01-01 00:00:00-05:00 2000-01-02 00:00:00-05:00  0
2000-01-02 00:00:00-05:00 2000-01-03 00:00:00-05:00  0

In [15]: pd.read_hdf('/tmp/my.h5', 'data2').index.levels[0]
Out[15]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2000-01-01 00:00:00-05:00, 2000-01-02 00:00:00-05:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: EST5EDT

In [16]: pd.read_hdf('/tmp/my.h5', 'data2').index.levels[1]
Out[16]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2000-01-02 00:00:00-05:00, 2000-01-03 00:00:00-05:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: EST5EDT
```

Comment: Would make more sense to throw exception indeed. Thanks for adding the issue for that!

Comment: Found one more issue of similar nature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830952/changing-timezone-on-pandas-datetimeindex-when-concatenating-dataframes-in-pytho