# Changing timezone on pandas DatetimeIndex when concatenating DataFrames in Python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm on pandas 0.14.1. Have two DataFrames both indexed by timezone-aware DatetimeIndex:

```
import pandas as pd
ix1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=pd.Timestamp('20140715', tz='EST5EDT'), end=pd.Timestamp('20140717', tz='EST5EDT'), freq='D', tz='EST5EDT')
ix2 = pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.Timestamp('2014-07-11 00:00:00', tz='EST5EDT'), pd.Timestamp('2014-07-21 00:00:00', tz='EST5EDT')])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=ix1, columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=ix2, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

Both indices having timezone, one with freq and one without:

```
df1.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-07-15 00:00:00-04:00, ..., 2014-07-17 00:00:00-04:00]
Length: 3, Freq: D, Timezone: EST5EDT


df2.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-07-11 00:00:00-04:00, 2014-07-21 00:00:00-04:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: EST5EDT
```

Then concatenating the two changes timezone to `UTC`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-07-15 04:00:00+00:00, ..., 2014-07-21 04:00:00+00:00]
Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: UTC
```

I wonder if this is a known bug or it has a particular reason.

Comment: this is a bug. need some code to figure out whether to recreate the tz (e.g. it has to be on all pieces and they have to be the same).

Comment: I think this works as long as both are > 2 in length (it is because an index of len(2) cannot have an inferred_freq, only a set freq).

Comment: Have my own version of concat in my code, where I'm exactly doing that. Though could be useful to show the bug, or find the reason... Thanks for quick reply!

Comment: Yeah, it actually works most of the time, it was hard to create the example.

Comment: issue is here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7795, pull-requests are welcome!

Comment: Will wait next release, but thanks!